# How to count contiguous range of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as following:

```
VideoId    StartTime EndTime EntityMid
1001         1         2        a
1001         2         3        a
1001         7         8        b
1001         10        11       a
1001         11        12       a
1002         4         5        c
1002         7         8        c
```

I want to have the following result:

```
VideoId    EntityMid duration
1001        a         2
1001        b         1
1001        a         2
1002        c         1
1002        c         1
```

I tried window function and self-join, but looks like doesn't work. Really appreciate for your help!

My wrong sql code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * 
    LEAD(EntityMid) OVER(PARTITION BY videoId ORDER BY StartTime) AS lead_EntityMid, 
    LEAD(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY videoId ORDER BY StartTime) AS lead_EndTime
)
FROM a
) b
WHERE EntityMid = lead_EntityMid 
AND EndTime + 1 = lead_EndTime
```

Comment: Why are there two records at the end with `EntityMid = 'c'`?  I would have expected that island to be reported as a single record.  Can you include the SQL you have tried so far?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the two `c` rows don't have `StartTime(n+1) = EndTime(n)`

Comment: We expect that you tried something to solve the problem so far, please show us your effort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Since the Starttime and endtime are not contigunous, so it will be reported two record seperately.

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan  Thanks for suggestion. I have pasted my wrong sql code.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra end parentheses `)` in your "wrong" code.  And possibly a superfluous `*` in your sub-`SELECT`

Comment: Can't understand what you are trying to solve.

Comment: How do you get from table to result?  What's the logic?  Without explanation, how do you expect people to understand how you magically turn records from table to result?

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands problem.

For your particular data, you can use `left join` to determine if an "island" begins.  Then use a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select t.videoid, t.EntityMid,
       max(t.EndTime) - min(t.StartTime) as duration
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when tprev.EntityMid is null then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by t.videoid order by t.StartTime) as grp
      from t left join
           t tprev
           on t.videoid = tprev.videoid and
              t.EntityMid = tprev.EntityMid and
              t.StartTime = tprev.EndTime
     ) t
group by t.videoid, t.EntityMid, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22a952cc6c9db4ed3f676d82beae47e0) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: This does not return the data that the OP asked for. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af594317d2cc8d49214267792dc55cb6

Comment: @VBokšić . . . Thank you for setting up the dbfiddle.  I left the `grp` out of the `group by`.  It works now:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=735afcbe4eb8c62a77a01aea0b737ef3.

Comment: You are welcome :) Still not getting the same as here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b05a3e10942640488b32c5285ec6158 and what OP asked under "I want to have the following result:".

Comment: @VBokšić . . . Fixed and checked this time.

Comment: Great, now it is close. One more outer select to remove this min and max results and that is it. Too bad OP is not active :)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff It works for me. Really appreciate for your smart approach!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can do it even better and optimize this bunch of sub-query's but for now this is what I have done:

Created table and inserted values:

```
create table myTable (VideoId int, StartTime int, EndTime int, EntityMid char);

insert into myTable values (1001, 1, 2,  'a');
insert into myTable values (1001, 2, 3,  'a');
insert into myTable values (1001, 3, 4,  'a');
insert into myTable values (1001, 7, 8,  'b');
insert into myTable values (1001, 10, 11,'a');
insert into myTable values (1001, 11, 12,'a');
insert into myTable values (1002, 4, 5,  'c');
insert into myTable values (1002, 7, 8,  'c');
```

And the query:

```
select VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , Durationes
from
(
select VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , sum(Durationes) Durationes
       , seq_nbr
from (
select VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , Durationes
       , sum(new_grp) OVER ( PARTITION BY  VideoId ORDER BY VideoId, StartTime) AS seq_nbr 
from
(
select VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , (EndTime - StartTime ) as Durationes
       , StartTime
       , CASE
            WHEN  grouped = LAG (grouped) OVER ( PARTITION BY  VideoId  ORDER BY VideoId, StartTime, EntityMid)
                THEN  0
                ELSE  1
        END AS new_grp  
from 
(
select VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , StartTime
       , EndTime
       , count('1')
       , case 
            when ((LEAD(StartTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime))-StartTime) = 1 and VideoId = (LEAD(VideoId, 1) OVER (ORDER BY VideoId))  then 1
            when (StartTime - (LAG(StartTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime))) = 1 and VideoId = (LAG(VideoId, 1) OVER (ORDER BY VideoId))  then 1
         end grouped
from myTable 
group by VideoId
         , StartTime
         , EndTime
         , EntityMid
order by VideoId
         , StartTime
         ,EndTime
         , EntityMid
) a
) b
) c
group by VideoId
       , EntityMid
       , seq_nbr
) d;
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b05a3e10942640488b32c5285ec6158